# ServiceWorkerの動作ドメインについて

Tags: http, push-notification

現在ServiceWorkerを用いたWebPushを実装しています。

現段階ではプッシュ通知にデータをpayloadで載せるのではなく，FetchAPIを用いてデータを取りに行くようにしています。
しかし，FetchAPIでアクセスされるAPIのヘッダには"Access-Allow-Control-Origin"を適切に指定する必要があるかと思います。

そこで質問なのですが，ServiceWorkerは https://example.com/ 以下で登録される場合において，Access-Allow-Control-Originはどのように設定するのが適切でしょうか。
（https://example.com を指定すれば良いのでしょうか？）

Service WorkerはFetchAPIにアクセスするときにどのアドレスからアクセスするのでしょうか？

ご回答よろしくお願いいたします。